# What is this plant from a package of mixed flower seeds?

Tags: identification, houseplants, flowers, containers

I got a bunch of flower seeds off of amazon back during the summer. The majority of them are dead now, but this is the last remaining and I am not sure what flower plant it is. I planted back in the summer, and as you can see, it has not grown much. It is the only surviving of its kind but I have no information on its identity. I would appreciate help identifying it so I know if I should pull it or leave it.

(Click for a larger version)

[image]

Comment: Where are you located? Was it from a seed packet? Vegetable or flower?

Comment: Would help to know where you're located (to determine what your local weeds are - looks like a weed but I'm really not sure what it is).

Answer (score 2):

My first guess is Jasminium polyanthum. However, it has not grown much. It may just be a weed that came up in the soil you had - this can happen all the time, even when you are careful to keep weed seed away.

Try re-potting it and giving it food/water, it may start to grow faster. Perhaps move the pot around to see if it prefers different conditions, ie more sun, less sun.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, I've got one idea - the leaf arrangement and the greenness of the stems are very reminiscent of Jasmine nudiflorum, which is a shrub often grown with support as a climber, but I can't imagine why a seed of this would have been included in a bunch of mixed flower seeds, contents of those are usually annuals or perennials.

Comment: hmm. I don't see even the beginnings of a woody stem. I see a rosette of compound leaves coming from the base. Growing like an herbaceous biennial.

Comment: @J.Musser true, and its only an idea, but I'd not expect to see a woody stem in a plant this size anyway.